# AgGrid: Custom resize icon for column resizing

Tags: css, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Is there any way to add custom resize icon?
I didn't find any suitable solution in the docs. I've tried to add custom CSS rules for `ag-header-cell-resize` without any success.

[image: ag-grid resize icon]

Answer (score 1):

That is just a `div` element with a gray background color, not an icon. You can customize it using css. The example below changes the resize div color to `red` and increase its size:

```css
.ag-header-container .ag-header-cell-resize {
  width: 15px;
}
.ag-header-container .ag-header-cell .ag-header-cell-resize::after {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

### Live Demo

https://plnkr.co/edit/V7rbCuvYCVjkJIOb